# Monomorphisms of Boolean Algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra

Suppose $f: B->C$ is a homomorphism between Boolean Algebras such that $ker(f)=0$.  Is $f$ necessarily a monomorphism? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a)=f(b)$, with $a\neq b$, then $a\nleq b$ or $b\nleq a$.
Suppose, without loss of generality, that $a \nleq b$.
Thus $a \wedge b' \neq 0$.
Now, taking $c = a \wedge b'$, we have
$$f(c) = f(a) \wedge f(b') = f(a) \wedge (f(b))' = f(a) \wedge (f(a))'=0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't see immediately why $a^b'=0$ forces $a<=b$

Comment: Ok, I think I can fill in the gaps.  Thanks a lot!  a <= 1 -> a <= (b v b') -> ab + ab' = a which means that ab=a if a^b' = 0 contrary to a not <= b.

Comment: @PaulEpstein That's correct. And you see that this answers positively the question you posted, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Thanks.  The text I'm reading talks about a - b which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: $a-b$ might be a notation for $a \wedge b'$, somehow...

Comment: in sets, $A\setminus B = A \cap B'$, and that could explain the notation